# operador && que no devuelva booleano

Tags: javascript, operador

Estoy haciendo el siguiente ejercicio:
-Si "numero" es divisible entre 3, devuelve "fizz"
-Si "numero" es divisible entre 5, devuelve "buzz"
-Si "numero" es divisible entre 3 y 5 (ambos), devuelve "fizzbuzz"
-De lo contrario, devuelve el numero.
Mi código es el siguiente

```
function divisible(numero) {
    if (numero % 3 === 0) {
        return 'fizz';
    } else if (numero % 5 === 0) {
        return 'buzz';
    } else if (numero % 3 === 0 && numero % 5 === 0) {
        return 'fizzbuzz';
    } else {
        return numero;
    }
}
```

me funcionan todos menos el que debe devolver "fizzbuzz". Supongo que estoy utilizando mal el operador &&

Comment: Probablemente no funciona por la precedencia de operadores

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema está en el orden de los `if`, si el número es divisible entre ambos, siempre entra en la primer condición porque es divisible entre 3. Si no es divisible entre 3 verifica entre 5.

Primero deberías hacer la verificación del && y luego verificar los números por separado.

Quedaría algo así:

```
function divisible(numero) {
  if (numero % 3 === 0 && numero % 5 === 0) {
      return "fizzbuzz";
    } else if (numero % 5 === 0) {
        return "buzz";
    } else if (numero % 3 === 0) {
      return "fizz";
  } else {
    return numero;
  }
}
```

Espero haber ayudado a despejar tu duda, quedo a las órdenes.

Comment: Luis S. Romero. Acabo de probarlo y funcionó. Muchas gracias

Comment: Por favor, a las órdenes. Favor no olvidar cuando te lo permita (Generalmente 10 minutos después de plantear la pregunta), darle al visto al costado de la pregunta para marcar la respuesta como aceptada, así no queda pendiente para siempre, ayuda a mejorar la reputación y ayuda a otros a saber que la respuesta está probada y funciona para que puedan aprovecharla. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Esta es la respueta correcta

```
function divisible(numero) {
  if (numero % 3 === 0 && numero % 5 === 0) {
      return "fizzbuzz";
    } else if (numero % 5 === 0) {
        return "buzz";
    } else if (numero % 3 === 0) {
      return "fizz";
  } else {
    return numero;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hola Roberto, bienvenido y gracias por tu colaboración, las respuesta que son solo código, son consideradas de baja calidad, te sugiero que edites la tuya, y expliques de que forma resuelve el problema planteado, así evitarás que sea cerrada y/o recibir votos negativos, ver [como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.